# AuthenticationStatus return NOT_DONE when use a custom form and a basebase identity store

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, glassfish, jaspic, jacc

I have spent days on updating myself to Java EE 8, there is a problem I'v encountered when used `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` and `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition` together.

I am using Glassfish v5, NetBeans 9 nightly and Java 8.

What I did is just want to update the [app-mem-customform sample](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/blob/master/test/app-mem-customform) in the security-soteria(Java EE Security 1.0 RI) **test** folder, and what I have changed is  using `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition` to replace the memory based dummy `IdentityStore`.

When I starts up the application, and try to login, got the following info from the NetBeans console.

```
Info:   Activating javax.security.enterprise.identitystore.DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition identity store from com.hantsylabs.example.ee8.security.ApplicationConfig class
Info:   Activating javax.security.enterprise.authentication.mechanism.http.CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition authentication mechanism from com.hantsylabs.example.ee8.security.ApplicationConfig class
Warning:   RAR8705: Invalid value for property dynamic-reconfiguration-wait-timeout-in-seconds : null
Info:   initializing database...
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   Initializing Soteria 1.0 for context '/security-custom-form-db'
Info:   Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.3.2 ( 20170627-2139 e63598abf2ed2bb1a24674f308a734e0dce18a72) for context '/security-custom-form-db'
Info:   Monitoring jndi:/server/security-custom-form-db/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Info:   Loading application [_Security_1.0:_Custom_Form_Authentication_with__DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition] at [/security-custom-form-db]
Info:   _Security_1.0:_Custom_Form_Authentication_with__DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition was successfully deployed in 3,288 milliseconds.
Warning:   RAR8705: Invalid value for property dynamic-reconfiguration-wait-timeout-in-seconds : null
Info:   RAR7115: Unable to set ClientInfo for connection
Info:   authentication result:NOT_DONE
```

**Info:   authentication result:NOT_DONE**  from my `LoginBean`, print the returned  `AuthenticationStatus`.

My security config file is:

```
@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        loginToContinue = @LoginToContinue(
                loginPage = "/login.faces",
                errorPage = "" // DRAFT API - must be set to empty for now
        )
)
@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition(
        dataSourceLookup = "${'java:global/MyDS'}",
        callerQuery = "#{'select password from caller where name = ?'}",
        groupsQuery = "select group_name from caller_groups where caller_name = ?",
        hashAlgorithm = Pbkdf2PasswordHash.class,
        priorityExpression = "#{100}",
        hashAlgorithmParameters = {
            "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Iterations=3072",
            "${applicationConfig.dyna}"
        } // just for test / example
)
@ApplicationScoped
@Named
public class ApplicationConfig {

    public String[] getDyna() {
        return new String[]{"Pbkdf2PasswordHash.Algorithm=PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512", "Pbkdf2PasswordHash.SaltSizeBytes=64"};
    }

}
```

I also included the `DatabaseSetup`  to insert users at the application starts up. The file is copied from [app-db sample](https://github.com/javaee/security-soteria/blob/master/test/app-db).

My complete codes can be found [here](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/security-custom-form-db).

What is the correct way to use `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` and `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition` seamlessly in projects?

**Update**, I have just tried to use `@FormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition` and `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition`, it works, the codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/ee8-sandbox/tree/master/security-form-db). So is this a bug of `@CustomFormAuthenticationMechanismDefinition`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my app.
Adding `.newAuthentication(true));` to authenticate parameters helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with custom form and JSF with Glassfish 6.2.5,
at first same **NOT_DONE** thing happened to me as well, but then I figured out
that I had errors in SQL statements for `@DatabaseIdentityStoreDefinition`.
Unfurtunately in this case it just silently returns **NOT_DONE**, no clues in glassfish logs, etc.

Maybe something was fixed since that time.